# perl: add a new directive in Apache Virtual Host file

Tags: regex, perl

For a pattern looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>
  Directive1
  Directive2
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to insert a new line with the string `Directive3` before `</VirtualHost>`. Note that they can be several `<VirtualHost/>` declarations in the file but that they all have unique IP:PORT pair. This is what I have so far:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(<VirtualHost 127\.0\.1\.1:81>[^(<\/VirtualHost>)+])(<\/VirtualHost>)/$1\n\tDirective3\n$2/ims' $file
```

Which broken down gives:

- has `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>`
- followed by
- has everything except `</VirtualHost>`
- followed by
- `</VirtualHost>`

But this does not match anything :(...

Any idead?

Comment: `[^(<\/VirtualHost>)+]` doesn't mean `has everything except </VirtualHost>`

Comment: should the plus sign be after the right bracket ] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perl -p` reads the file one line at the time. You can use `-0777` to make it read the whole file.

Or you could use something like:

```
perl -pE '(/<VirtualHost +127\.0\.0\.1:81>/ .. /<\/VirtualHost>/) =~ /E/ and say "\tDirective3"'
```

Comment: it works!!! i am learning Perl and i know it has bad press for its complex syntax but i find it rather awesome so far :) thanks @Qtax